# CSS getting crushed

Tags: css

I am following this tutorial on styling breadcrumbs. Trying to make breadcrumbs that have a nice arrow format. The problem is the display gets crushed when the screen size shrinks.

Can anyone figure out how to keep this from happening in the code pen? Here is the tutorial. The code pen is at the bottom. I've tried overflow hidden, setting a height... kinda stuck. : https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/[image]

[image]

Comment: Its because they're using `float:left` to align everything on one line. Floats wrap when the content is too big for the container... You might consider setting fixed widths or using flexbox

Comment: use display: flex on the container and remove floats. Flex will force them to align untli you decide to break them and stack them one under the other.

Comment: even on css tricks its the same if you shrink it will crush